# Torus two-point blocks and a-monodromy for the 2D Ising CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, ising-model

I was trying to use some concrete example to understand the a-monodromy and b-monodromy in the proof of the Verlinde formula. On the Yellow Book, I found the following results for the torus two-point blocks for $\langle \epsilon(z) \epsilon(0) \rangle_{torus}$ for the Ising CFT,
[image]

However, I don't know how to interpret the results (sorry, I didn't try to derive them) and my confusions are the following.

1. The diagrams used by the books does not seem to allow for taking the limit $z\rightarrow 0$. (Or, the diagrams are not expected to be analytic near $z=0$) Therefore I would like to interpret the three formula on the right hand side as the following three diagrams respectively,
   [image]
   so that they are consistent with the fact that the formula are analytical at $z=0$ and it gives the correct character when we consider the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z \langle \epsilon(z) \epsilon(0) \rangle_{torus}$.
2. If I made the above re-interpretation, the diagrams and the formula yield opposite results for the a-monodromy (which is square of the braiding matrix). The diagrams say the a-monodromy for the three blocks are $1,1,-1$. Though the formula say they are $-1,-1,1$, which is actually inconsistent with the Verlinde formula, which says the a-monodromy is given by 
   \begin{equation}\phi_i(a) \chi_j = \lambda_j^{(i)}\chi_j , \lambda_j^{(i)} = S_{ij}/S_{0j}\end{equation}

I'm wondering whether I made a mistake in my analysis or the results on the book are wrong. It will also be great if someone can tell me some other references on torus two point function or some concrete demonstration on the Verlinde formula. Please let me know if my question is unclear to you. Thanks!